# How to create hook_ds_fields_info()?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to add few custom field using display suite in drupal7 and for that i want to use hook_ds_fields_info(). I just know basics for that. Don't know how to create the hook for this. Do I need to create a different file and call the function?

Comment: [http://drupal.org/node/361112](http://drupal.org/node/361112) may be a good starting point for your research